# Find owner class of a method in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, types

I'm writing decorators, and part of what I need to do is discern whether a function is a function or a method. Is there a way I can find what class a given method is a part of?

e.g. If I was to run this code, what could I write in `getOwner` to make `exampleFunc` print something like `<class '__main__'.Example>`?

```
class Example:
    def method(self):
        print("I'm a method")

def exampleFunc(func):
    owner = getOwner(func)
    print(owner)

test = Example()
exampleFunc(test.method)
```

Comment: Functions are not "owned" by classes, so this question has a flawed premise.

Comment: @coldspeed whatever the specific terminology, can I find the class that this function is a part of?

Comment: Regardless of the terminology, functions are not owned by classes, and functions do not understand or keep track of any information regarding their classes, so no.

Comment: Your best bet would be to iterate over every class in your scope, and see if any of its methods match the method that your function was passed.

Comment: @coldspeed that would work for some cases, but what if I was passed a `__call__` method?

Comment: Test the `id` value, and it should still work.

Comment: For example, `Example.method in Example.__dict__.values()` will return `True`.

Comment: @coldspeed make that an answer and I'll accept it, that works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to the classes defined in your scope, you'd need to check for each one:

```
def exampleFunc(f):
    class_list = [...]
    return any(f in vars(c).values() for c in class_List)
```

This will return `True` if function `f` is an instance method. However, if you wish to return the actual class name:

```
def exampleFunc(f):
    class_list = [...]
    for c in class_list:
        if f in vars(c).values():
            return c.__name__

    return 'global function' if 'lambda' not in f.__name__ else 'lambda'
```

Note that this does not work for `__dunder__` methods, and methods that your class inherits. For example,

```
class A:
    def f1(self): pass

class B(A):
    def f2(self): pass

print(vars(B)) 
mappingproxy({'__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              'f2': <function __main__.B.f2>})
```

Note that `f1` is not a part of `B`'s `mappingproxy`.

Comment: +1 for using `dunder` and for your approach. Here is a [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DunderAlias) where the word `dunder` comes from.

Answer (score 5):

If all you need to do is figure out of the thing behaving like a function is a method or a function, that is one purpose of the `types` module.

```
import types

def is_method(f):
    return type(f) == types.MethodType
```

In the event that the function-like object is a method, you can find its parent class as follows.

**Update** Patched for Python3 compatibility.

```
def method_parent(f):
    return f.__self__
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @coldspeed "I'm writing decorators, and part of what I need to do is discern whether a function is a function or a method."

Comment: "what could I write in getOwner to make exampleFunc print something like <class '__main__'.Example>?"

Comment: I haven't seen this `f.im_self` before. Can you provide any supporting claim or documentation relating to this?

Comment: It won't work as you have posted it here. Furthermore, I do not see a python3.x equivalent.

Comment: @coldspeed You could use the `getmembers()` function if you would like instead. And I stand by it being a reasonable interpretation of OP's question that he wants to know how to identify if something is a method -- the other language in the question suggesting his own attempts and thoughts at solving the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171887/discussion-between-hans-musgrave-and-coldspeed).

Comment: `type(Example.method)` returns "function" on python3. Are you sure your first method works as well?

Comment: If you use `type(Example.method)`, you don't have an instance the method could be bound to, and it is in fact a function. Try `type(Example().method)`. That works fine in Python2 and Python3.

Comment: `if isintance(f, types.MethodType): return f.__self__.__class__` doesn't guarantee this is the defining class... but would allow you to get the `mro` to search the tree.

Comment: @AChampion That's a thought. Do you think the intended application uses instances or classes?

Comment: @HansMusgrave The OP is using an instance.